# Open Internet Explorer from Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I currently developing a ASP.NET web application.

The application is designed for Google Chrome. I would like to pop out IE when printing is involved because Chrome lack preview etc. at a button click the IE should open. Here's the code:

```
protected void btn_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost/storeapp/printpage.aspx?orderno=" + Request.QueryString["orderno"].ToString() + "");
}
```

Here I have  passed a particular `orderno` to the URL. But when I click nothing happens. I have set IE as default web browser. Why is this?

There is no error shown? Any ideas?

Comment: How about starting iexplore.exe directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do will only open an IE window on the SERVER not on the client machine. You cannot (for obvious security reasons) start a process on the clients machine.

You cannot force a client browser to open a link in a different browser.

Comment: k fine don't open in client side... but y doesn;t open in server

Comment: please have more courtesy and respect when people attempt to help you with your problem, pheonix4eva.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force server to open process on `Client` side, what you have now is opening it on the `Server` side which is not desired behavior I believe.